# How i can delete spaces betwen strokes Python

Tags: python, space, stroke

I have a python script parser, and an output, I receive a lot of strokes with spaces between lines, how I can delete them?
I have strokes:

```
dog

dgfdfg

dgdfgdf

dfgdfgdfg
```

I want to obtain:

```
dfgdf
dgfdfg
dgdfgdf
dfgdfgdfg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace multiple newline characters with a single one like below:

```
import re
lines = re.sub("\n+", "\n", lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option:

```
text = """dog

dgfdfg

dgdfgdf

dfgdfgdfg"""

text = "\n".join(text.split())
```